# Javascript exercism solution. Why is one better than the other?

Tags: javascript

I solved the Gigasecond exercism in Javascript with this solution. I would like to know what I could have done better:

```
var gigasecondConverter = function(unformattedDate) {
  this.date = function() {
    return beginAtStartOfDay(Number(unformattedDate) + 1000000000000)
  }
}

beginAtStartOfDay = function(number) {
  date = new Date(number)
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setHours(0);
  return date;
}

module.exports = gigasecondConverter
```

Why is this solution better?

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  function Gigasecond(birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.interval = 1000000000000;
  };

  Gigasecond.prototype.date = function() {
    var gigasecondCelebrationDate = new Date(this.birthDate.getTime() + this.interval);
    return this._beginningOfTheDay(gigasecondCelebrationDate);
  };

  Gigasecond.prototype._beginningOfTheDay = function(date) {
    date.setSeconds(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setHours(0);
    return date;
  };

  module.exports = Gigasecond;

})();
```

Why is the self-executing function and usage of prototypes better than just defining the date method directly on the function? Also is there a difference between using Number and getTime()?

Comment: There are a plethora of ways to write Javascript modules. Some are probably objectively better, if you were to measure aspects of them, but in general they are all valid. It depends on which convention you prefer, and what you fellow programmers expect you to use.

Comment: is usage of prototypal inheritance here more memory efficient? Also why do we wrap everything in a self-executing function? Is the self-executing function necessary?

Comment: Adding methods to a prototype is more efficient in theory, but in practice it is not always necessarily the case. It depends on how you write the code. You will have to measure your code to get any usable answers to that question. Google for something like "*javascript prototype vs closure performance*" to find articles/benchmarks.

Comment: What's the advantage of having a self-executing function here? Is it the scoping of variables locally?

Comment: It is used for scoping.

Answer (score 5):

WoW! in the **first code** :

1. *beginAtStartOfDay* is created in the global scope.
2. *gigasecondConverter* is created in the global scope.
3. then you return beginAtStartOfDay in *gigasecondConverter*

okey now let me explain a bit what appened to your poor memory :D.
*beginAtStartOfDay* is memorized in the global scope, then you use it in *gigasecondConverter* so he creates another *beginAtStartOfDay* in the *gigasecondConverter* scope, its memory waste.

but the **biggest memory waste** is ***EACH*** time you gonna call 
*gigasecondConverter* you will create a ***NEW*** instance of *beginAtStartOfDay*. Imagine just using *gigasecondConverter* 100 times and 99 times you do memory waste ! poor memory :D

in **the second** :

1. *Gigasecond* is created in the global scope.
2. *date* is created in the *prototype* of *Gigasecond*.
3. *_beginningOfTheDay* is created in the *prototype* of *Gigasecond*.

Now ***EACH*** time you gonna call *Gigasecond* it will Only create **ONE** instance of *_beginningOfTheDay* even if you call 100 times, it will always call the ***SAME*** prototype function of *Gigasecond*.

Prototype in JavaScript is very powerfull! using it for a function you gonna call and return many times is always a good thing for your memory. **:)**

Comment: Why do we use the self-calling function??

Comment: You mean this? 

(function(args) {
//things
 })();

this is to make all your vars and functions not to be in conflict with other functions and vars with the same name, the function creates a new scope and execute it immediately , so it can't be conflicting with any vars or function name of any other JavaScript file. it's a good way to do.

Mostly if you want to do a plugin you HAVE to use it, to no make it conflicting with the main.js of the user. :)

Comment: Can you clarify this: "but the biggest memory waste is EACH time you gonna call gigasecondConverter you will create a NEW instance of beginAtStartOfDay. Imagine just using gigasecondConverter 100 times and 99 times you do memory waste !" Why would only 99 new instances be created? You mean 99 new variables are created? Why aren't there 100 new instances created?

Comment: When you return something a variable or a function and you put it into a variable, each time you put it in a variable the langage creates a Copy of that function or variable. In your first code, imagine you want to keep 10 dates in variables. he will creates 10 new instance of the function that returns him, because the JavaScript Gargage collector won't destroy any function if it's reference is still in using (the reference of the date variable). I tried to be as much clear as I can, but there must be something like tutorial memory Javascript somewhere out there. :)